# excel - count days in between 2 dates as one occurence per day

Tags: excel, date, countif

I have a list of hotel reservations including columns for guest name, room type (eg. standard room), arrival date and departure date.

I now want to calculate how many standard rooms I have occupied on a specific date.

Eg. how many standard rooms are occupied on Jan XX?

- John - Standard Room - Jan 1st - Jan 3rd
- Mary - Deluxe Room - Jan 2nd - Jan 4th
- Bob - Standard Room - Jan 4th - Jan 5th
- Tim - Standard Room - Jan 1st - Jan 5th

Result:

- on Jan 1st totally 2x Standard Rooms are occupied (John + Tim)
- on Jan 2nd totally 2x Standard Rooms are occupied (John + Tim)
- on Jan 3rd totally 1x Standard Room is occupied (Tim - Note: John is not counted since he is checking out on Jan 3rd hence not staying the night)
- on Jan 4th totally totally 2x Standard Rooms are occupied (Tim + Bob)
- on Jan 5th no rooms are occupied since both Tim and Bob will checkout on this day.

I have a row with dates ranging from 01/01/2016 to 31/01/2016 spread across 31 columns, but am unable to make this work via COUNTIFS and SUMIFS in a dynamic formula.

Much appreciate some help on this.
Thanks

Comment: You might want to look into using pivot tables, which would give you some real database functionality in your worksheet.  And thanks for including me in the reservations.

Comment: @timBiegeleisen just because of that I will edit the post and upgrade you to a Suite Room ;) Still, would be great if there is a formula solution for this since I dont like to set a pivot as I am not administrating the data input.

Comment: If you included some sample data it might make the question more clear.

Comment: as a hint (start date in C1:C4, end date D1:D4, room type B2:B4, the date to check against A7): `=COUNTIFS($C$1:$C$4,"<="&A7,$D$1:$D$4,">"&A7,$B$1:$B$4,"Standard Room")` would show the count of `Standard Room` at the given day... this should be anything you need to make it work ;)

Answer (score 0):

Consider this screenshot:

[image]

The dates in column F are entered manually. The formula to calculate the results in column G is in G2

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(F2>=$C$2:$C$5),--(F2<$D$2:$D$5),--($B$2:$B$5="standard"))
```

copy down.